# Subtract time from date using format string

Tags: c#

If I have a date and time in a DateTime object, can I remove say 10 minutes, or 24 hours etc from the date and time using a format string?

So if I have 1/1/1990 12:30:00pm and I wanted to remove 1 hour from it, can I use a format string?

**edit**

i need to store diary entries and the user can select a reminder type. so 1 hour before hand. so then i'd like to store the format string in a db that i can get and apply to a datetime to get the reminder date time

Comment: Do you want to perform datetime arithmetics or just to format datetime in some specific manner? What is `remove 10 minutes`? Did you actually mean `subtract 10 minutes`?

Comment: arithmetic yes and subtract, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to convert to a `DateTime` object and then back to the formatted string (if that's what you need):

```
var time = DateTime.Parse("1/1/1990 12:30:00pm");
time = time.AddMinutes(-10);
string timeString = time.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Comment: Actually, if I convert my reminders to minutes, even if they are weeks in advance, then I can simply store the minute amount and use AddMinutes.  That's crazy enough to work,

Comment: it depends on the resolution you need, you can use AddSeconds, AddDays, AddMonths, AddYears etc. depending on what you need. Also should probably accept @DoesItWorks answer since it was similar

Answer (score 4):

Something like this might do what you need.  Not sure what you mean by subtracting an hour using a format string though.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1, 12, 30, 0);
string s = dt.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

Comment: i need to store diary entries and the user can select a reminder type.  so 1 hour before hand.  so then i'd like to store the format string in a db that i can get and apply to a datetime to get the reminder date time

Comment: @griegs: c# interaction with db is a wide question. You probably need to check DoesItWork's answer as a valid since it answers to your original question about subtraction and ask another one with details about what you use, what you have tried, etc

Comment: Then the answer is, no, you cannot subtract an hour using a .NET date/time format string.  You would need to store the length of time represented by the reminder type.  You would then get the diary entry datetime and subtract that length using the method described above (or one of the other methods .NET provides).

Comment: That's what I was thinking yeah.  I like the answer from @BrokenGlass as it comes close to what i was looking for.  +1 for the help tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your query if you have..

DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr unit)
Example:

YourDate = DATE_SUB(1/1/1990 12:30:00pm, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)

YourDate = DATE_SUB(1/1/1990 12:30:00pm, INTERVAL 12 MINUTE)

YourDate = DATE_SUB(1/1/1990 12:30:00pm, INTERVAL 45 SECONDS)